# Why won't my While loop, loop?

Tags: c#, while-loop, console-application, break, nested-loops

Okay I have tried this from every angle I can think of and I think I am over complicating things as per usual!

I am building a console c# application that will ask the user to input a price of an item bought and then for a "customer code" depending on this customer code a certain discount will be applied.

I used a switch statement for this and it all works with error checking (using while loops to keep asking until a correct input is recognised) It is the final part I'm struggling... the console asks the user if they would like to enter more data (jump back to the start of the main loop) with my code if the user inputs an incorrect input it asks again as required also if the user enters 'N' the program terminates. But the bit that isn't working is if the user enters 'Y' they should be able to go back to the start and input more data but this doesn't work =/ I used a "break;" statement to break out of the exit loop and back into the main loop...

At this point the character is 'Y' so the main loop should still be running but instead the console does nothing it just has the cursor on a blank line... it asks for no input and it does not say "press any key to continue". I have gone into as much detail as possible and I'm sorry for the essay =/ ... below is my code... hopefully someone can spot where I am going wrong!

UPDATED: I should also note that I have tried the main loop with (=='Y') and set the variable as 'Y' so that it does the first loop. I have also changed it to a do while loop with the same statement so that is runs through first with a blank character then if it is changed to a 'Y' the loop condition should have been excepted =/

UPDATE: I've noticed the error with my calculation before you all think I'm more of an idiot =/ LOL

```
namespace W7Task1
{
    class W7Task1
{
    // "Main" method begins the execution of the C# application
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        char customerCode = '\0';
        double initialCost = 0;
        string customerType = "";
        double finalPrice = 0;
        string userInput = "";
        char continueChar = '\0';

        while (continueChar != 'N')
        {
            while (initialCost == 0)
            {
                Console.Write("\nPlease input the cost of the item: ");
                userInput = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
                try
                {
                    initialCost = Convert.ToDouble(userInput);
                }
                catch
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nPlease input a number!");
                }
            }

            while (customerCode == '\0')
            {
                Console.Write("\nPlease input your customer code: ");
                userInput = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
                customerCode = Convert.ToChar(userInput);
                customerCode = char.ToUpper(customerCode);

                switch (customerCode)
                {
                    case 'A':
                        customerType = "Managerial Staff";
                        finalPrice = (initialCost / 100) * 30 - initialCost;
                        Console.WriteLine("\nThe initial cost of the item is: {0:c}\nYour customer type is: {1}\nThe items final price is: {2:c}\n", initialCost, customerType, finalPrice);
                        break;
                    case 'B':
                        customerType = "Sales Staff";
                        finalPrice = (initialCost / 100) * 20 - initialCost;
                        Console.WriteLine("\nThe initial cost of the item is: {0:c}\nYour customer type is: {1}\nThe items final price is: {2:c}\n", initialCost, customerType, finalPrice);
                        break;
                    case 'C':
                        customerType = "Account Customers";
                        finalPrice = (initialCost / 100) * 8 - initialCost;
                        Console.WriteLine("\nThe initial cost of the item is: {0:c}\nYour customer type is: {1}\nThe items final price is: {2:c}\n", initialCost, customerType, finalPrice);
                        break;
                    case 'D':
                        customerType = "Cash Customers";
                        finalPrice = (initialCost / 100) * 5 - initialCost;
                        Console.WriteLine("\nThe initial cost of the item is: {0:c}\nYour customer type is: {1}\nThe items final price is: {2:c}\n", initialCost, customerType, finalPrice);
                        break;
                    case 'E':
                        customerType = "Credit Card/Cheque";
                        finalPrice = (initialCost / 100) * 0 - initialCost;
                        Console.WriteLine("\nThe initial cost of the item is: {0:c}\nYour customer type is: {1}\nThe items final price is: {2:c}\n", initialCost, customerType, finalPrice);
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("\nError Please input a valid Customer Code\n");
                        customerCode = '\0';
                        break;
                }
            }

            while (continueChar == '\0')
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Would you like to input more data?");
                userInput = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());

                if (char.TryParse(userInput, out continueChar))
                {
                    continueChar = char.ToUpper(continueChar);

                    if (continueChar == 'Y')
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (continueChar == 'N')
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Thankyou for using this application");
                        System.Environment.Exit(0);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Please input a 'Y' or 'N'");
                        continueChar = '\0';
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Please input a valid character!");
                }
            }
        }
    }// End of "Main" method
}// End of "W7Task1" class
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's happening is that, after the user enters `'Y'`, the outer loop (namely, `while (continueChar != 'N')`) will continue to loop indefinitely, but none of the inner loops (starting from `while (initialCost == 0)`) will have their conditions satisfied, since their variables (such as `initialCost`) would retain the values that were assigned in the former iteration.

The easiest fix is to move all your variable initializations to inside the outer loop. Change your code from:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    char customerCode = '\0';
    double initialCost = 0;
    string customerType = "";
    double finalPrice = 0;
    string userInput = "";
    char continueChar = '\0';

    while (continueChar != 'N')
    {
        while (initialCost == 0)
        {
        // ...
```

...to:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    char continueChar = '\0';

    while (continueChar != 'N')
    {
        char customerCode = '\0';
        double initialCost = 0;
        string customerType = "";
        double finalPrice = 0;
        string userInput = "";

        while (initialCost == 0)
        {
        // ...
```

**Edit**: If you want to preserve your variable declarations at the top of your method, you could separate their declaration and initialization like so. This would ensure that they're reset on each iteration of the inner loop, whilst keeping your tutor happy.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    char customerCode;
    double initialCost;
    string customerType;
    double finalPrice;
    string userInput;
    char continueChar = '\0';

    while (continueChar != 'N')
    {
        customerCode = '\0';
        initialCost = 0;
        customerType = "";
        finalPrice = 0;
        userInput = "";

        while (initialCost == 0)
        {
        // ...
```

Comment: I knew it was something really simple! I just had one of those "Oh yeah... duh!" moments. Thank you so much =]

Comment: I missed it at first glance too. But it became obvious when I stepped through the code. Try learning how to use the Visual Studio debugger; it helps immensely in these situations.

Comment: I'm a first year student and they have only told us to "run without debugging" =/ personally the only difference I see between them is that debugging will close the console when no more code is to be executed and without debugging will keep the window open asking you to exit manually.

Comment: we are also asked to declare all variables at the top of the method or I miss out on presentation marks =/ I shall have to ask my tutor tomorrow if I will lose the mark for moving it down slightly as its not as if I've split them all up and it helps functionality

Comment: You will see the difference between the two modes if you set a breakpoint in your code. The last edit in my code should address your tutor's requirement.

Comment: Thank you... I reset the variables at the end after the exit loop that way they aren't so close together =P

Comment: The drawback to that is that you're initializing the variables at two different places, which makes your code less maintainable (since, if you need to change the 'default' value for one of the variables, you'll need to update two places in your code).

Comment: ahhh that is true... I shall have a chat with my tutor and see what she would prefer. Thanks for your help =]

Answer (score 3):

You are not resetting your variables.

When the user has come out of the exit loop the variables are as follows

```
continueChar == 'Y'
customerCode != '\0'
initialCost != 0
```

This means all your while loops will not trigger.

Move your variable declarations or initialization inside the main loop.

Comment: I'd copy and paste my comment for the above answer but that would be rude so Thank you for your response also =]

Answer (score 0):

Have you stepped through your application using the debugger (press 'F10' in Visual studio)?

You're not resetting the 'initialCost' variable to 0.

Comment: I am as I'm doing "blackbox testing" too (which I'm confused about so I have just listed everything that happened on each test and I can arrange it into blackbox format when I understand it. Thank you for your response